# Laravel ajax request is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Okay, probably best if i show you the relevant code snippets to this problem and talk you through it.

First ill start with the actual Ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modelLink').click(function(){
        var reviewID = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/flyout',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                'reviewID':reviewID
            },
            success: function( data ){
                alert('Success Alert');
                console.log(data.value);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

As you can see i am passing a reviewID to the URL flyout. I have put in the ajax setup the CSRF-TOKEN as Laravel requires this on every post request.

So lets now show the route it is going to.

```
Route::post('/flyout','DashboardController@flyout');
```

This should now route to my dashboard controller to the action "flyout"
For testing purposes i haven't done anything in my controller except the below:

```
public function flyout(){
    $result = 'hello';
    return Response::json($result);
}
```

Great this should be a simple 3 step process. Send request to controller, respond with data and then do something with the data.

Weirdly i actually do get the alert('Success Alert'); which tells me that it has had a response, as i always assumed the success part of ajax meant it sent and received a response.

Now when i go

```
console.log(data)
```

This shows all the html that is in my webpage. Even showing the  all the way down to .... strange.

Now when i go

console.log(data.value)

This then write "undefined"

Does anyone know what could be happening?

**EDIT::**

This is the network on developer tools

[image]

**EDIT::**

After going into my middleware , i commented out this section

```
if (!Auth::user()->can($request->segment(1))) {
            Flash::warning("You don't have the correct permissions to access that page.");

            return new RedirectResponse(url('/dashboard'));
        }
```

Now that i have done this the network part looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Is the HTML being returned a Laravel error page?

Comment: @MattMcDonald no , it is actually sending back the html of the page. So if i inspect element it matches all the html there which is weird

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue myself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modelLink').click(function(){
        var reviewID = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'/flyout/' + reviewID,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function( data ){
                alert('Success Alert');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

and there was something in my middleware causing trouble.

Thanks for everyone trying to help